# Changing tab item header on runtime (WPF, c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml, interface

I am using a form in WPF with C#, thing is, that I've assigned colors and styles to the XAML, and now I am changing them programmatically (since I want to change the color (theme) of the whole application when I press a button).
I have been able to change everything's color through the C# code, but I cannot bring myself to do so with the tab item headers.
Is there any way to do that? Or should I do something to the XAML?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: paste the code that you have to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a name to tab header item whose header you would like to change on runtime.

In XAML:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Name="header_one" Header="One"/>
    <TabItem Name="header_two" Header="Two"/>
    <TabItem Name="header_three" Header="Three"/>
</TabControl>
```

In your Code attach an event to the button that will change Header details

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

header_one.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
header_one.Background = Brushes.Blue;

}
```

Note: This does not change color of header when selected (default color in this case is white). If you want to change the selection color the only way i can think of is using XAML styling.
I've tried this and it works just fine, unless you're doing something wrong in your code. Please if you can show your code to get a better answer.

Comment: This appears to work, thank you so much. Thing is, the app should change colours depending on where it is launched, and I do not know if there is any way to define an style that does that depending on a boolean variable for example.